# Updating the classic PHP/MySQL Maps API store locator for use with Places API and no PHP/SQL?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We've been using Google's [Store Locator Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) code since 2009 to provide the geographical search component for a simple, flat database of local voluntary organisations all providing roughly the same type of service *to* a geographical area in a single country, but not *from* a mappable point of presence.

The search volume is very low, the results are rows of plain text on a web page. It works.

#### So what's the problem?

When you've got system run by unpaid volunteers, you don't always have time to keep code up to date. And it seems overkill to be running a LAMP server or even shared hosting just to serve a singe page to search for "nearest 5".

#### Google Places Javascript API to the rescue!

Sounds a perfect fit for something like the [JavaScript library component](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) [[FAQ]](https://developers.google.com/places/faq).

The Places Search API even comes with a handy `nearby` method, using either radius or a bounded area. This would make a perfect Google web app, or possibly a page on our Google Apps for Non Profits service. No server to rent, no software to update.

And as a bonus, no messing with any CRUD - I can setup a simple Google Spreadsheet as the datasource, and anyone who can edit a spreadsheet can update the back-end details. Remember, we're only talking about max 5 results from 300 or so entries on a 5 column table. I've selectively pulled data from sheets 50x larger into [Tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) and presented the data with [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) without problems. Just not having to do a geo radius search.

#### But there's a catch.

To use the extremely neat and compact Places API methods, the data must actually already exist on Google Maps, and fit into one of a range of [types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types). It wouldn't be correct to add our list of 300 or so service to Google Maps as businesses or services, as maps are for a specific location-based service, rather than a collection of outreaching-volunteers in a particular area. If we could find a way of combining the ease of the places API nearby radius search with a custom data source like the Maps API example, all problems would be solved. Except, I know of no such method. So...

#### The Question:

*I want to allow searching of up to 5 results from a custom flat table in a 50 mile radius without needing the LAMP stack solution Google suggest in their 2009 pre-Places solution.*

Am I on the right lines above but missing something obvious, or even not so obvious?
Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Guidance or nudges in the right direction are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the Maps Engine API could work for you:

- Stores your feature data in table format and offers GUI access to editing (though not as familiar as a spreadsheet).
- Offers radius and bounds search on features.
- Ability to limit the results to a specific number (you mentioned 5).
- Returns GeoJSON which can be loaded into a Maps API app with the new Maps.Data object.
- Free.

https://developers.google.com/maps-engine

So you could use jQuery to call your data:

https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/hello-world#javascript

using a query like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/tableId/features
  ?intersects=CIRCLE(lng lat, radius)&limit=5&version=published&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

So now you have a JSON object accessible to your JS. You can pass that JSON to Maps.Data:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

and also use it to populate any sidebar, infowindows, etc.

Might work for you?

Comment: Fantastic! Absolutely perfect - thank you so much. The quota for the free version is fine, and I ran the sample code in the chrome console with my API key and had data back in under a minute, compared with struggling for an entire day yesterday. I have no idea why Google haven't linked to this as an alternative service, like they do for other services. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: Right on - glad to hear it!

Comment: Just got a bad news email from Google - Maps Engine is now deprecated, no new signups, and is closing on Jan 29th 2016. What a shame - feels like it only just got off the ground. Or map.